How to export TopologicPy graph to Neo4j
I am trying to store a TopologicPy graph in Neo4j. I tried the codes below according to the TopologicPy documentation:
from topologicpy.Topology import Topology
from topologicpy.Graph import Graph
from topologicpy import Neo4j

IFC_file_path = "sample.ifc"
graph_topo = Graph.ByIFCPath(IFC_file_path)

username="..."
password="..."
url="..."

graph_neo4j = Neo4j.Neo4j.ByParameters(url=url, username=username, password=password)
topo_neo4j = Neo4j.Neo4j.AddGraph(neo4jGraph=graph_neo4j, graph=graph_topo, labelKey='None', relationshipKey='None')

But I got the error below. Anyone knows where the problem is? Are there some ways to store a TopologicPy graph to Neo4j? Thanks!
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 4
      1 # Create an instance of the Neo4j graph
      2 graph_neo4j = Neo4j.Neo4j.ByParameters(url=url, username=username, password=password)
----> 4 topo_neo4j = Neo4j.Neo4j.AddGraph(neo4jGraph=graph_neo4j, graph=graph_topo, labelKey='None', relationshipKey='None')

File c:\Users\Howie.Liu\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\graphrag\lib\site-packages\topologicpy\Neo4j.py:336, in Neo4j.AddGraph(neo4jGraph, graph, labelKey, relationshipKey, mantissa, tolerance)
    334     nodeName = str(values[keys.index(labelKey)])
    335 n = py2neo.Node(nodeName, **pydict)
--> 336 neo4jGraph.cypher.execute("CREATE INDEX FOR (n:%s) on (n.name)" %
    337         n.nodelabel)
    338 tx.create(n)
    339 nodes.append(n)

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'cypher'

